# How to reach the hidden crate in Shaman's Path?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn, horizon-zero-dawn-the-frozen-wilds

In the Shaman's Path, after the *Stalkers* part and a couple of swinging bridges, there's a rock arch and above it, on the right, I can spot a crate with my focus but I can't figure out a way to reach it.

Since it may contain something rare or unique I don't wanna miss it.

Comment: Is this the crate with a zip wire leading down from it near the waterfall operated swing bridge?

Comment: @greg-449 yap, that's it, how can you get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the crate with a zip wire leading down from it near the waterfall operated swing bridge:

Drop down in to the stream below the bridge and move downstream until you see yellow climbing points leading up to the ledge with the crate. Then just climb up.

Comment: Pretty disappointing content, but your answer is correct!